# NixOS & NixOps declarative group management and services

Tags: linux, permissions, user-groups, nixos

### Is it possible to manage groups in a declarative way in NixOS and NixOps?

I would like to be able to create a new group in a `configuration.nix`, and add users to it. I have not been able to find any options available to do this, and am having issues with groups manually added being removed by new nixops deployments.

### What I've Tried

I've tried modifying the groups of users created by services in a `configuration.nix` file:

```
system.activationScripts = {
  mediaGroup = ''
    echo "Adding `media` group"
    getent group media || groupadd media
  '';
};

users.users.plex.extraGroups = [ "media" ];
users.users.radarr.extraGroups = [ "media" ];
users.users.sonarr.extraGroups = [ "media" ];
users.users.deluge.extraGroups = [ "media" ];
```

And also by modifying the services, plex, radarr, sonarr, and deluge to take an additional group option:

```
{ config, pkgs, lib, ... }:

with lib;

let
  cfg = config.services.sonarr;
in
{
  options = {
    services.sonarr = {
      openFirewall = mkOption {
        type = types.bool;
        default = false;
        description = ''
          Open ports in the firewall for the media server
        '';
      };

      user = mkOption {
        type = types.str;
        default = "sonarr";
        description = "User account under which sonarr runs.";
      };

      group = mkOption {
        type = types.str;
        default = "sonarr";
        description = "Group under which sonarr runs.";
      };

    };
  };

  config = mkIf cfg.enable {
    systemd.services.sonarr = pkgs.lib.mkForce {
      description = "Sonarr";
      after = [ "network.target" ];
      wantedBy = [ "multi-user.target" ];
      preStart = ''
        test -d /var/lib/sonarr/ || {
          echo "Creating sonarr data directory in /var/lib/sonarr/"
          mkdir -p /var/lib/sonarr/
        }
        chown -R ${cfg.user}:${cfg.group} /var/lib/sonarr/
        chmod 0700 /var/lib/sonarr/
      '';

      serviceConfig = {
        Type = "simple";
        User = cfg.user;
        Group = cfg.group;
        PermissionsStartOnly = "true";
        ExecStart = "${pkgs.sonarr}/bin/NzbDrone --no-browser";
        Restart = "on-failure";
      };
    };

     networking.firewall = mkIf cfg.openFirewall {
      allowedTCPPorts = [ 8989 ];
    };

    users.users = mkIf (cfg.user == "sonarr") {
      sonarr = pkgs.lib.mkForce {
        uid = config.ids.uids.sonarr;
        home = "/var/lib/sonarr";
        group = cfg.group;
        extraGroups = [ "media" ];
      };
    };

    users.groups = mkIf (cfg.group == "sonarr") {
      sonarr = pkgs.lib.mkForce {
        gid = config.ids.gids.sonarr;
      };
    };

  };
}
```

On each `nixops deploy` I get:

```
my_server...> activating the configuration...                                                                                                                                         
my_server...> removing group ‘media’                                                                                                                                                  
my_server...> warning: user ‘media’ has unknown group ‘media’                                                                                                                         
my_server...> warning: user ‘plex’ has unknown group ‘media’                                                                                                                          
my_server...> warning: user ‘radarr’ has unknown group ‘media’                                                                                                                        
my_server...> warning: user ‘sonarr’ has unknown group ‘media’
```

And if I check each users group I get the following even if I manually added the user to a group with `usermod`:

```
[root@my_server:/var/lib]# groups sonarr
sonarr : nogroup
```

### Context

The lack of a shared group between these services is causing permission issues preventing automation of file copying from deluge to the plex media locations by sonarr and radarr. I think this is the only problem with it working, I have also configured the deluge service to use a `umask` of `002` and the permissions seem to be correct.

```
[root@my_server:/var/lib/deluge/Downloads]# ls -l && cd MovieFolder && ls -l
drwxrwxr-- 2 deluge media 4096 Aug 26 11:39  MovieFolder
-rw-rw-r-- 1 deluge media 2420763104 Aug 26 11:08  TheMovie.mkv
```

Also the message from sonarr and radarr:

```
No files found are eligible for import in /var/lib/deluge/Downloads/MovieFolder
```

And an example log message:

```
18-8-26 12:47:51.3|Error|DownloadedEpisodesImportService|Import failed, path does not exist or is not accessible by Sonarr: /var/lib/deluge/Downloads/MovieFolder
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to define the group `media` as well.

Either define it explicitly first:

```
users.groups.media = {};
users.users.plex.extraGroups = [ "media" ];
```

or add a member to the group right away:

```
users.groups.media.members = [ ... ];
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Could you add a little explanation for why you're suggesting OP try these things?